# Заполнить матрицу треугольником

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

решение должно построить пирамиду из заданного входного списка целых значений.
Номера сортируются по возрастанию сверху вниз, слева направо.

Пустые пространства заполняются нулями.
Чтобы заставить симметричные входные числа пирамиды чередуться с нулями.
Входные:

---

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 9, 4, 5);
```

Выходные:

---

```
int[][] expected = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 2, 0, 3, 0},
            {4, 0, 5, 0, 9}};
```

Мое решение:

---

```
public int[][] buildPyramid(List<Integer> inputNumbers) {
    boolean flag;//Флаг для возможности/невозможности построения пирамиды
    int[][]matrix;//Получившаяся матрица

    System.out.println("Введенная последовательность: " + inputNumbers);

    int size = inputNumbers.size();//Проверяем размер полученного массива

    //Проверим, является ли данное число треугольным
    int count = 0;int rows = 1;int cols = 1;
    while(count < size){
       count=count+rows;
       rows++;
       cols=cols+2;
    }
    rows = rows-1;//Актуальное число строк
    cols = cols-2;//Актуальное число столбцов

    if(size==count) {
        flag = true;//Если возможно построить матрицу
    }else flag = false;

    if(flag){
        List<Integer> sorted = inputNumbers.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("Отсортированная последовательность по возрастанию: " + sorted);
        System.out.println("Количество элементов в последовательности: " + size);
        System.out.println("Число столбцов(cols) матрицы будет равно: " + cols);
        System.out.println("Число строк(rows) матрицы будет равно: " + rows);
        System.out.println("*******СТРОИМ МАТРИЦУ*******");

        matrix = new int[rows][cols];//Задаем размерность матрице

        int centr = (cols/2);//Находим центральную точку матрицы
        int i = 1;//ячейка строк
        int c = 1;//счетчик цикла
        count = 0;


//В этом цикле у меня затык, я не понимаю как заполнить его цифрами из последовательности в заданном порядке
        while(i <= rows) {
            while(count < i) {

                matrix[i-1][rows-c] = inputNumbers.get(c-1);
                count++;
                c++;
            }
            count=0;
            i++;
        }

        for(int [] a: matrix)//выводим матрицу на экран
        {
            for(int b: a)
                System.out.print(b+" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }//Выбрасываем исключение
    else{
        throw new CannotBuildPyramidException();
    }


    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Ну вообще-то под термином "треугольная матрица" обычно понимают немного другую конструкцию... так что если уж Вы придумываете собственное толкование, объясните его остальным.

Comment: Правка внесена=)

Comment: `я не понимаю как сделать это, чтоб заполнялось нулями` - нулями надо заполнять сразу после инициализации, чтоб потом не геморроится с логикой. Дальше лишь вставляются числа в нужные ячейки

Comment: окей, он по умолчанию нули. Тогда мне надо получается заполнить цифрами...

Comment: А в чём сложности? Чтобы задача имела решение, количество исходных чисел должно быть представимо как N*(N+1)/2. Тогда размер матрицы N x (2N-1), а в строке M заполняем M позиций через одну, начиная с позиции N-M+1.

Comment: Я не понимаю как провести это через цикл...формулы то я давно провел уже эти

Answer (score 3):

Напишу середину (остальное не трогал):

```
if (flag) {
    List<Integer> sorted = inputNumbers.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Отсортированная последовательность по возрастанию: " + sorted);
    System.out.println("Количество элементов в последовательности: " + size);
    System.out.println("Число столбцов(cols) матрицы будет равно: " + cols);
    System.out.println("Число строк(rows) матрицы будет равно: " + rows);

    /******* ЗАПОЛНЯЕМ МАТРИЦУ НУЛЯМИ *******/
    matrix = new int[rows][cols];//Задаем размерность матрице
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        Arrays.fill(row, 0);
    }

    /******* СТРОИМ ТРЕУГОЛЬНИК *******/
    int center = (cols / 2);//Находим центральную точку матрицы
    count = 1; // сколько чисел будет в строке
    int arrIdx = 0; // индекс массива

    for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < rows; i++, offset++, count++) {
        int start = center - offset;
        for (int j = 0; j < count * 2; j +=2, arrIdx++) {
            matrix[i][start + j] = sorted.get(arrIdx);
        }
    }

    /******** ВЫВОДИМ МАТРИЦУ НА ЭКРАН *******/
    for(int [] a: matrix)//выводим матрицу на экран
    {
        for(int b: a)
            System.out.print(b+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}//Выбрасываем исключение
else{
     throw new CannotBuildPyramidException();
}
```

Не знаю, уловите ли смысл. Надо было нарисовать матрицы визуально где-нибудь и по ним представить логику.

Смысл в том, что

- В каждой строке будет увеличиваться количество цифр: 1, 2, 3 и т.д. За это отвечает `count`.
- Также на каждой строке будет происходить смещение относительно центра для отрисовки цифр `center - offset;`
- Отрисовка будет вестись с шагом 2 (`j +=2`), а так как количество цифр `count` в таком случае может оказаться меньше шага `j`, то счетчик будет пробегаться не по количеству `count`, а `count * 2`

Скорее всего это можно всё сократить. Но в целом должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант треугольной матрицы
Например,
для 1
{{1}}
Для 2
{{1}
{2, 3}}
и т.д.

```
    public static int[][] rows(int count) {
    int[][] triangle = new int[count][];
    int r = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        triangle[i] = new int[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < triangle[i].length; j++) {
            triangle[i][j] = r++;
        }
    }
    return triangle;
}
```